# How do I pull up a command prompt on an Azure Website instance?

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface, azure

I am running an instance of the Ghost blogging platform on Azure.  Setting it up was simple, I used a template from the gallery and it was set up in no time.  FTP'ing into it to do work like template adjustment was simple to set up, but I am lost as to how I am going to upgrade it or make sure node is up to date.  How can I pull up a command line, or powershell window that is running on that instance of my website to run commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a Kudo Console which will get you a console for the website.  You can watch this video ([Exploring the Super Secret Kudu Debug Console - with David Ebbo](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Windows-Azure-Friday/Exploring-the-Super-Secret-Kudu-Debug-Console-with-David-Ebbo)) up on Channel 9 to see how this works.

In essence you go to the root of the Kudu deployment for your site.  This is reached by going to the https://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net and entering your git credentials.  You can then click on the Debug Console link on that page.

Comment: Is there a way to get access to the kudu shell without setting up a functioning scm deployment?

Comment: I enabled a local git repository as it was the least disruptive option.  Once I did that the scm page became active and all was good.  Thanks.